# Celery no longer logs results / time

Tags: python, logging, task, celery

Using Celery 3.x, the workers would log when a task completes, and the actual time it took, like described here [Celery time statistics per-task-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534311/celery-time-statistics-per-task-name)

After upgrading to 4.1, celery workers no longer log task results, not even unhandled exceptions, although for the latter you can easily use a signal handler, I'm wondering what changed or what's wrong, logging when a task completes was important.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was related to the celery hijack loggers setting, setting it to False fixes the issue.